# create a thread over a toat message

Tags: android, toast, telephonymanager

I have the following code:

```
String state= bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)
{
Toast toast= new Toast(context);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.Length_LONG);
toast.makeText(..).show();
toast.show();
}
```

I need to keep the toast up until the person answers to the phone. How to do that?
I know I have to create and start a thread when I have incoming number and stop the thread when the person answers. how to accomplish this?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this..

```
 Toast.Length_LONG gives toast for only 3.5 seconds..
```

so.. create a countdowntimer of 3.5 seconds like this..in your activity's onCreate

```
 String state= bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
 MyCount counter;
counter=new MyCount(3500,1000);
counter.start();
```

MyCount class..

```
   public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
 public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
}
 @Override
public void onFinish() {
 if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER){
  Toast toast= new Toast(youractivity.this);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.Length_LONG);
toast.makeText(..).show();
toast.show();
  counter= new MyCount(3500,1000);
 counter.start();
    }

}
 @Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }
}
}
```

this continuously shows toast till you answer the call..or your incoming call ends due to timeout..

Comment: where do i have to start the counter? in if condition?

Comment: I have errors: the state is not recognized in the new class. My base class is called IncommingCalls.java

Comment: what should i have to fill to youractivity?

Comment: no, i have errors. what is state in the new class and what is youractivity??

Comment: All this code should be written in your primary activity...in which you are trying to diaplay the toast.. and by "youractivity" i mean name of your activity..